# Qt Toolbar animation based on opacity

Tags: qt, qtoolbar, qpropertyanimation

`Toolbar(SelectionToolBar)` is allowed `LeftToolbarArea`. and is presently hidden. When i take the mouse to the left border of the application, it will come with animation defined on opacity. This is working fine. But the problem is when I move over the mouse i.e. hover on `toolbuttons` , all toolbuttons will hide though I can click buttons, its working. Only the toobutton display(view/look) is getting hidden. I am suspecting "fade_effect" it is going out of scope. Any solution?

```
bool evenfilter(...)
{
 ... 
  QGraphicsOpacityEffect* fade_effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect();
  ui->SelectionToolbar->setGraphicsEffect(fade_effect);
  QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(fade_effect, "opacity");
  animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
  animation->setDuration(3000);
  animation->setStartValue(0.01);
  animation->setEndValue(1.0);
  animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
//animation->start();
  ui->SelectionToolbar->show();
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: it looks like a QToolbar bug for me.

Comment: @eyllanesc I remember you have answered the similar issue about opacity 0.99, but I cannot find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**<del>This shall be a BUG</del>**

**It's a BUG as @KYL3R mentioned**

Demo to reproduce:

```
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

class ToolBar : public QToolBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ToolBar(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QToolBar(parent)
    {
        setGraphicsEffect(&mFadeEffect);
        mFadeAnimation.setTargetObject(&mFadeEffect);
        mFadeAnimation.setPropertyName("opacity");
        mFadeAnimation.setStartValue(0.0);
        mFadeAnimation.setEndValue(1);
        mFadeAnimation.setDuration(3000);
        mFadeAnimation.start();
    }
    virtual ~ToolBar() {}

private:
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect  mFadeEffect;
    QPropertyAnimation      mFadeAnimation;
};

auto toolbar = new ToolBar();
toolbar->addAction("action 1");
toolbar->addAction("action 2");
toolbar->addAction("action 3");

addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, toolbar);
```

**Temp solution:**

change

```
mFadeAnimation.setEndValue(1);
```

to

```
mFadeAnimation.setEndValue(0.99);
```